# How to have multiple manage policies in an aws role using cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a following cloud formation script and I want to add two Managed Policies to a Role.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Bringing up the whole stack
Resources:
# IAM role
   PublishingActionExecutionRole:
     Type: AWS::IAM::Role
     Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action:
         - sts:AssumeRole
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
          - lambda.amazonaws.com
```

However when I run this script it just add the first policy not the second one.

Any one know the trick to it?

Comment: If you swap the order of your two policies, does the other policy get added, or the same one?

Answer (score 0):

This template seems to work:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  PublishingActionExecutionRole: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```